# Form input is not displayed correctly, can anyone spot the mistake?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

So I am trying to display an input of a form. If you click the submit the input is not displayed but the innerText, can someone spot the mistake I made?

```js
function showName(e){
    var wateringzoneName= document.getElementById("namewateringzone").value;
    document.getElementById("show").innerText = "wateringzoneName";        
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namewateringzone" name="namewateringzone" placeholder="Namen der Bewässerungszone eingeben">
<input type="submit" onclick="showName()" name="submit" value ="Hinzufügen">
                                                <span id="show"></span>
```

Comment: On where it's not displaying?

Comment: On the same page, fixed it tough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap variable with quote or it will be just a string.

```js
function showName(e){
    var wateringzoneName= document.getElementById("namewateringzone").value;
    document.getElementById("show").innerText = wateringzoneName;        
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namewateringzone" name="namewateringzone" placeholder="Namen der Bewässerungszone eingeben">
<input type="submit" onclick="showName()" name="submit" value ="Hinzufügen">
                                                <span id="show"></span>
```